# 'ParseError: bad input' in python turtle

Tags: python

I am very new to python and yesterday started working with python turtle. I'm making a program that allows you to input a grid that will be shown as 3D cubes with turtle. I'm getting the error 'ParseError: bad input on line 27' when I am trying to allow the user to create each line of the grid.

```
from turtle import * 
import random 
window = Screen()
window.bgcolor(0,123,167)
pen = Turtle()
pen.color(0,0,0)
pen.penup()
pen.speed(5)
def drawcube():
  pen.pendown()
  pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()+30)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()+30,pen.ycor())
  pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()-30)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()-30,pen.ycor())
  pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()+30)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()+10,pen.ycor()+10)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()+30,pen.ycor())
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()-10,pen.ycor()-10)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()+10,pen.ycor()+10)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()-30)
  pen.goto(pen.xcor()-10,pen.ycor()-10)
  pen.penup
pen.goto(-150,-50)
spots = [[j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)] 
for x in range(len(spots)):
  spots[x] = input("draw row"+x", with '-' being empty and '=' being a cube.")
```

I'm getting an error on the last line where I ask the user to input the line.

Comment: Titles like "I'm not sure whats causing this error in my [...] code" fit to maany questions here. Can you please change the title to a more specific one?

Comment: not sure if this is much better but i guess its more specific

Comment: Can you add whole traceback?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. As an aside, `import *` is almost always bad practice, and variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. In any case, the error was caused by a typo, so I'm voting to close this as such.

Answer (score 0):

nvm im sped there needed to be another + sign after x

Answer (score 0):

In line 22 it should be `pen.penup()`, the brakets are missing. And you need to do

`spots[x] = input("draw row"+str(x)+", with '-' being empty and '=' being a cube.")` in the last line, as you cannot add strings and ints without conversion.